# hadoop too many open files issue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

what could be causing many open files issue?

> java.io.IOException: Got error, status message opReadBlock BP-493425312-172.20.178.11-1399995954120:blk_1449181880_375614544 received exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hd_data/disk4/hadoop/hdfs/data/current/BP-493425312-172.20.178.11-1399995954120/current/finalized/subdir96/subdir194/blk_1449181880 (Too many open files), for OP_READ_BLOCK, self=/172.20.178.55:39870, remote=am1plccmrhdd05.r1-core.r1.aig.net/172.20.178.105:1019, for file /CONSUMER/LHD/Americas/Policy_Admin/ALIP/Ingest/PENDING_WORKLOAD/RD_ASCII_Print.TSV, for pool BP-493425312-172.20.178.11-1399995954120 block 1449181880_375614544

Comment: what could be causing many open files issue?

Comment: Lots of namenode / datanode requests, obviously. And if you have other services on the same server, that only adds to the problem ... Just increase the open file count

Comment: Related https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/3332/datanode-does-not-pick-up-correct-ulimit-on-secure.html

Comment: What is your limit set to?  From http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/configuration-parameters-what-can-you-just-ignore/ written in 2009 it recommends 16K.